# Difference between wp_list_categories and get_categories

Tags: categories

Whats the difference between the `wp_list_categories` and `get_categories`?

Wordpress codex says

> use get_categories if needs a function that does not format the results

what format is this referring to? Will it affect the performance if I use the other one? And if i want to display all the hierarchical custom taxonomy links on a page, should I use those two functions or use another one?

Comment: Have you actually tried using any of the functions. If you did, you have already answered your own question with *use get_categories if needs a function that does not format the results*

Comment: @Pieter Goosen kk i will go and test out first : ) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_list_categories` gives you HTML markup of links (`<a>`) to the categories while `get_categories` just returns the data to be used for whatever you wanted.

But actually [Pieter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31545/pieter-goosen) is right, in such cases just give it a try, nobody will get hurt ;)